# How can I edit the value of "bal"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database

I am trying to make a simple database using .json in JavaScript. How can I edit the value of "bal" of "player1"?

```
{
"player": [{
    "number": "1122", 
    "name": "player1",
    "bal": 0,     //How to change this 0 into 100?
    "role": "Owner of the MoS Game",
    "rank": "Normal"
}, {
    "DCNumber": "3344", 
    "name": "player2",
    "bal": 0,
    "role": "Helper",
    "rank": "Normal"
}, {
    "DCNumber": "5566",
    "name": "player3",
    "bal": 0,
    "role": "Player",
    "rank": "Normal"
}],

"rankCatagory": ["Normal", "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold", "Platinum", "VIP", "VIP+", "MVP", "MVP+", "MVP++"]
}
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
var rawdata = fs.readFileSync('Data.json');
var data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(data);
console.log("Successfully Loaded \"Data.json\"");

/*

What should I do to edit the value of bal?

*/
```

Comment: `data.player[0].bal = new_value`? Eventually loop through the player array if you want to change all the values for `bal` key.

Comment: Does the order of players matter?  If not, I would suggest converting player from an array to an object indexed by the player number/DCNumber

Answer (score 0):

```
data.player.find(p=>p.name=="player1").bal = 100;
```

Or instead of `.find(...)` simply `[0]` if it's always the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it for every player:

```
data["player"] = data["player"].map(el => {
    return {
        ...el,
        bal: 100    
    }
})
```

otherwise you should know the name:

```
const name = "player1"
data["player"] = data["player"].map(el => {
    if(el.name = name){
        return {
            ...el,
            bal: 100    
        }
    } else {
      return {
            ...el,
        }
     }
})
```